# How to get the Category TCMID's name/title through DD4T

Tags: dd4t

I have a Category TCMID and required a name of this through DD4T,

I am able to get allkyewords of this category, But unable to find any option to get the Category Name in DD4T View.

```
DD4T.Factories.TaxonomyFactory taxFactory = new DD4T.Factories.TaxonomyFactory();

string catgoryTcmUri = "tcm:45-6200-512"; // coming from app.config file

List<IKeyword> keyword = taxFactory.GetAllKeyword(catgoryTcmUri);
//by this keyword object, I am getting all child keywords.
```

In current scenario, I am getting the category TCMID from config file, I want to get the name/title of this value.

Is there any other way to get this?

Comment: in which context you want to do it, in Templating or CD side? Please explain it in your question.

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar, I need it, this in razor view in DD4t

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code you use for getting the keywords, I'm sure that improves your chances on a useful answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a component or page which contains a value from the category, you can get to the category's ID through:

```
component.Categories[...].ID
```

If this is not the case, you will need to retrieve the category from Tridion using the CD api. I think this is possible with an ItemTypeCriteria combined with an ItemTitleCriteria, like this:

```
Criteria typeCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(512);
Criteria titleCriteria = new ItemTitleCriteria("MyCategory");
Query q = new Query(new AndCriteria(typeCriteria, titleCriteria));
```